# cpanminus install throwing segmentation faults

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault, cpanm

CentOS 6.6 on VMWare Fusion throws this error:

```
Fetching
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7021.tar.gz
... OK Configuring App-cpanminus-1.7021 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: ExtUtils::MakeMaker, Module::Build
--> Working on ExtUtils::MakeMaker Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/B/BI/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.04.tar.gz
... OK Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Command used:

```
# curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

Running CentOS 6.6 on XenServer 6.2 throws a slightly different error:

```
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7021.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring App-cpanminus-1.7021 ... OK
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a [bug](https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus/issues/421).

Started encountering segmentation faults with v1.7020 #421

> tthayer commented an hour ago
>
> I'm using Centos 6.5 x86-64. The
>   installation script for this started failing and giving segmentation
>   faults when attempting to install any CPAN packages, including
>   --self-upgrade. I'm not well-versed enough in perl to understand why this is happening, but none of the debug information I've see has
>   singled out any one library or system setting. Reverting to the 1.7019
>   release allows me to install CPAN packages again.

Bug is fixed in version 1.7022

Use `cpanm -V` to see your version.  Since `--self-upgrade` option also seg faults, you'll need to install again to update.